# How can I read special character in webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing an article managing android application, where articles are parsed through JSON.

All the values that are parsed by JSON are loaded in web view, but there are some special character that are not read by WebView.

```
{
    web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);               
    web1.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());              
    web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);             
    web1.loadData(c,"text/html", "UTF-32");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this way,

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(collection.getContext());
 webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, textWithQuotesIn, "text/html", "UTF-8", url);
```